# Panel overlapping issues in WPF mode

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating panel using the System.Windows.Forms.Panel, which contains the dynamically loaded data in drop down.

Code for Panel:

```
    this.panel1 = new Panel();
    this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 20);
    this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);

    this.panel2 = new Panel();
    this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 20);
    this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 250);
    Controls.Add(this.panel2);

    this.panelLblDisplay = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.panelLblDisplay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.panelLblDisplay.Name = "panelLblDisplay";
    this.panelLblDisplay.Text = "Item";
    this.panelLblDisplay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
    this.panelLblDisplay.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panelLblDisplay);

    this.panelDisplay = new TextBox();
    this.panelDisplay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80, 0);
    this.panelDisplay.Name = "panelDisplay";
    this.panelDisplay.ReadOnly = true;
    this.panelDisplay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(201, 20);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panelDisplay);

    this.btnExpand = new Button();
    this.btnExpand.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(281, 0);
    this.btnExpand.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.DropDownButton;
    this.btnExpand.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(19, 21);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btnExpand);

    this._tvItem = new TreeView();
    this._tvItem.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80, 0);
    this._tvItem.Name = "_tvItem";
    this._tvItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 250);
    this.panel2.Controls.Add(this._tvItem);
```

In wpf mode, when I click on the panel button, data is loading but, it is getting hide (overlap) under other controls. I can't see the data. However when I place this panel control in the end of my form, I am able to see the data. But, if I am placing this panel control in between some other controls (textbox, menubar), drop down is getting hide under.

Can anyone please suggest me on this. This issue appears only in WPF mode.

Comment: WPF is totally different from WinForms. What do you mean by "WPF mode"? In WPF you style your layout in XAML and not in your code. You can get started here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/introduction-to-wpf-in-vs

Comment: I'm assuming that you're referring to the [Airspace problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dwayneneed/2013/02/26/mitigating-airspace-issues-in-wpf-applications/). Read about that and **tag your question right** next time.